# JavaMail (TLS): Erratic failure to validate certification path

Tags: java, email, ssl, smtp, jakarta-mail

When attempting to validate a *TLS* connection using the *JavaMail* library, I **randomly** get the following validation error:

```
javax.mail.MessagingException: Can't send command to SMTP host;
nested exception is:
   javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

I'm running on a Linux machine, using *jdk1.7.0* and using the latest jdk's *cacerts* file (1.8.0_73 as of this writing), to which I've imported the smtp server certificate.

The smtp server is an *exchange* server, with plaintext TLS validation.

I say *randomly* because, at times, the connection succeeds, yet at other times it complains about being unable to recognize the certificate validation path and fails, seemingly without a given pattern.

Usually retrying the connection works, although the number of retries is not consistent, sometimes requiring none, sometimes 2 or 3, sometimes more than 20.

In order to remove any external influences, I wrote a simple mail sending application, which I'm using to investigate this issue (our application runs on Tomcat deployment), so I can be certain that the issue lies with one of these:

- JDK
- JavaMail library
- Network connectivity

My question is if anyone is aware of any limitations/bugs/issues that might be behind this behavior?

Retrying the connection suffices as a workaround for now, but our project needs make it undesirable as a permanent solution, since many messages are sent asynchronously, and in the case of a connection failing, users would get no feedback of the failure.

---

**EDIT:** Some more info

The server certificate was retrieved via openssl, namely this command:

```
openssl s_client -connect exchange.***.com:25 -starttls smtp 2>&1 | sed -ne '/-BEGIN CERTIFICATE-/,/-END CERTIFICATE-/p' > certificate.pem
```

Note that, without the *starttls* parameter, the command wouldn't work (took a while to figure out, as most resources online, including here on SO, would not include that step).
The (cleaned up) ouput of the raw openssl command is as follows:

```
depth=0 CN = smtpserver-ch-01
verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate

verify return:1
depth=0 CN = smtpserver-ch-01
verify error:num=21:unable to verify the first certificate
verify return:1
CONNECTED(00000003)
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/CN=smtpserver-ch-01
   i:/CN=smtpserver-ch-01
---
Server certificate
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
  *** CERTIFICATE DATA
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
subject=/CN=smtpserver-ch-01
issuer=/CN=smtpserver-ch-01
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read *** bytes and written *** bytes
---
New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is AES128-SHA
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1
    Cipher    : AES128-SHA
    Session-ID: ***
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Master-Key: ***
    Key-Arg   : None
    Krb5 Principal: None
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    Start Time: ***
    Timeout   : 300 (sec)
    Verify return code: 21 (unable to verify the first certificate)
---
250 XSHADOW
```

And the following is a **massive** print of the **javax.net.debug=ssl** output:
(Hope it's good form to post these massive text dumps)

```
Sending message to test@server.com; Attempt attempt 0 of 20...
keyStore is : 
keyStore type is : jks
keyStore provider is : 
init keystore
init keymanager of type SunX509
trustStore is: certs/cacerts_1.8.0_73
trustStore type is : jks
trustStore provider is : 
init truststore
adding as trusted cert:

   ** Standard certificates **

adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: CN=smtpserver-ch-01
  Issuer:  CN=smtpserver-ch-01
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: **********************************
  Valid from ddd MMM DD 00:00:00 CEST 2013 until ddd MMM DD 00:00:00 CEST 2018

adding as trusted cert:

   ** The rest of the standard certificates **

trigger seeding of SecureRandom
done seeding SecureRandom
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
Allow unsafe renegotiation: false
Allow legacy hello messages: true
Is initial handshake: true
Is secure renegotiation: false
%% No cached client session
*** ClientHello, TLSv1
RandomCookie:  GMT: XXX bytes = { XXX, ··· XXX }
Session ID:  {}
Cipher Suites: [TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5, TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV]
Compression Methods:  { 0 }
Extension server_name, server_name: [host_name: exchange.***.com]
***
main, WRITE: TLSv1 Handshake, length = **
main, READ: TLSv1 Handshake, length = ***
*** ServerHello, TLSv1
RandomCookie:  GMT: XXX bytes = { XXX, ··· XXX }
Session ID:  {XX, ··· XXX}
Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
Compression Method: 0
Extension renegotiation_info, renegotiated_connection: <empty>
***
%% Initialized:  [Session-1, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA]
** TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
*** Certificate chain
chain [0] = [
[
  Version: V3
  Subject: CN=smtpserver-ch-02
  Signature Algorithm: SHA1withRSA, OID = 1.2.840.113549.1.1.5

  Key:  Sun RSA public key, xxx bits
  modulus: ***
  public exponent: ***
  Validity: [From: ddd MMM DD 00:00:00 CEST 2013,
               To: ddd MMM DD 00:00:00 CEST 2018]
  Issuer: CN=smtpserver-ch-02
  SerialNumber: [    xxx ]

Certificate Extensions: 4
[1]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.19 Criticality=true
BasicConstraints:[
  CA:false
  PathLen: undefined
]

[2]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.37 Criticality=false
ExtendedKeyUsages [
  serverAuth
]

[3]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.15 Criticality=true
KeyUsage [
  DigitalSignature
  Key_Encipherment
]

[4]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.17 Criticality=false
SubjectAlternativeName [
  DNSName: smtpserver-ch-02
  DNSName: smtpserver-ch-02.domain.com
]

]
  Algorithm: [SHA1withRSA]
  Signature:

  *** SIGNATURE HEX DUMP ***

]
***
%% Invalidated:  [Session-1, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA]
main, SEND TLSv1 ALERT:  fatal, description = certificate_unknown
main, WRITE: TLSv1 Alert, length = 2
main, called closeSocket()
main, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
Failed attempt: javax.mail.MessagingException: Can't send command to SMTP host


Sending message to test@server.com; Attempt attempt 1 of 20...
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
Allow unsafe renegotiation: false
Allow legacy hello messages: true
Is initial handshake: true
Is secure renegotiation: false
%% No cached client session
*** ClientHello, TLSv1
RandomCookie:  GMT: XXX bytes = { XXX, ··· XXX }
Session ID:  {}
Cipher Suites: [TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5, TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV]
Compression Methods:  { 0 }
Extension server_name, server_name: [host_name: exchange.***.com]
***
main, WRITE: TLSv1 Handshake, length = **
main, READ: TLSv1 Handshake, length = **
*** ServerHello, TLSv1
RandomCookie:  GMT: XXX bytes = { XXX, ··· XXX }
Session ID:  {XXX, ··· XXX}
Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
Compression Method: 0
Extension renegotiation_info, renegotiated_connection: <empty>
***
%% Initialized:  [Session-2, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA]
** TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
*** Certificate chain
chain [0] = [
[
  Version: V3
  Subject: CN=smtpserver-ch-02
  Signature Algorithm: SHA1withRSA, OID = 1.2.840.113549.1.1.5

  Key:  Sun RSA public key, 2048 bits
  modulus: ***
  public exponent: ***
  Validity: [From: ddd MMM DD 00:00:00 CEST 2013,
               To: ddd MMM DD 00:00:00 CEST 2018]
  Issuer: CN=smtpserver-ch-02
  SerialNumber: [    xxx]

Certificate Extensions: 4
[1]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.19 Criticality=true
BasicConstraints:[
  CA:false
  PathLen: undefined
]

[2]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.37 Criticality=false
ExtendedKeyUsages [
  serverAuth
]

[3]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.15 Criticality=true
KeyUsage [
  DigitalSignature
  Key_Encipherment
]

[4]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.17 Criticality=false
SubjectAlternativeName [
  DNSName: smtpserver-ch-02
  DNSName: smtpserver-ch-02.domain.com
]

]
  Algorithm: [SHA1withRSA]
  Signature:

  *** SIGNATURE HEX DUMP ***
]
***
%% Invalidated:  [Session-2, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA]
main, SEND TLSv1 ALERT:  fatal, description = certificate_unknown
main, WRITE: TLSv1 Alert, length = 2
main, called closeSocket()
main, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
Failed attempt: javax.mail.MessagingException: Can't send command to SMTP host


Sending message to test@server.com; Attempt attempt 2 of 20...
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
Allow unsafe renegotiation: false
Allow legacy hello messages: true
Is initial handshake: true
Is secure renegotiation: false
%% No cached client session
*** ClientHello, TLSv1
RandomCookie:  GMT: XXX bytes = { XXX, ··· XXX }
Session ID:  {}
Cipher Suites: [TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5, TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV]
Compression Methods:  { 0 }
Extension server_name, server_name: [host_name: exchange.***.com]
***
main, WRITE: TLSv1 Handshake, length = **
main, READ: TLSv1 Handshake, length = **
*** ServerHello, TLSv1
RandomCookie:  GMT: *** bytes = { XXX, ··· XXX }
Session ID:  {XXX, ··· XXX}
Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
Compression Method: 0
Extension renegotiation_info, renegotiated_connection: <empty>
***
%% Initialized:  [Session-3, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA]
** TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
*** Certificate chain
chain [0] = [
[
  Version: V3
  Subject: CN=smtpserver-ch-01
  Signature Algorithm: SHA1withRSA, OID = 1.2.840.113549.1.1.5

  Key:  Sun RSA public key, 2048 bits
  modulus: ***
  public exponent: ***
  Validity: [From: ddd MMM DD 00:00:00 CEST 2013,
               To: ddd MMM DD 00:00:00 CEST 2018]
  Issuer: CN=smtpserver-ch-01
  SerialNumber: [    XXX]

Certificate Extensions: 4
[1]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.19 Criticality=true
BasicConstraints:[
  CA:false
  PathLen: undefined
]

[2]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.37 Criticality=false
ExtendedKeyUsages [
  serverAuth
]

[3]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.15 Criticality=true
KeyUsage [
  DigitalSignature
  Key_Encipherment
]

[4]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.17 Criticality=false
SubjectAlternativeName [
  DNSName: smtpserver-ch-01
  DNSName: smtpserver-ch-01.domain.com
]

]
  Algorithm: [SHA1withRSA]
  Signature:

  *** SIGNATURE HEX DUMP ***

]
***
Found trusted certificate:
[
[
  Version: V3
  Subject: CN=smtpserver-ch-01
  Signature Algorithm: SHA1withRSA, OID = 1.2.840.113549.1.1.5

  Key:  Sun RSA public key, 2048 bits
  modulus: ***
  public exponent: ***
  Validity: [From: ddd MMM DD 00:00:00 CEST 2013,
               To: ddd MMM DD 00:00:00 CEST 2018]
  Issuer: CN=smtpserver-ch-01
  SerialNumber: [    XXX]

Certificate Extensions: 4
[1]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.19 Criticality=true
BasicConstraints:[
  CA:false
  PathLen: undefined
]

[2]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.37 Criticality=false
ExtendedKeyUsages [
  serverAuth
]

[3]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.15 Criticality=true
KeyUsage [
  DigitalSignature
  Key_Encipherment
]

[4]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.17 Criticality=false
SubjectAlternativeName [
  DNSName: smtpserver-ch-01
  DNSName: smtpserver-ch-01.domain.com
]

]
  Algorithm: [SHA1withRSA]
  Signature:

    *** SIGNATURE HEX DUMP ***

]
*** ServerHelloDone
*** ClientKeyExchange, RSA PreMasterSecret, TLSv1
main, WRITE: TLSv1 Handshake, length = ***
SESSION KEYGEN:
PreMaster Secret:
  *** HEX DUMP
CONNECTION KEYGEN:
Client Nonce:
  *** HEX DUMP
Server Nonce:
  *** HEX DUMP
Master Secret:
  *** HEX DUMP
Client MAC write Secret:
  *** HEX DUMP
Server MAC write Secret:
  *** HEX DUMP
Client write key:
  *** HEX DUMP
Server write key:
  *** HEX DUMP
Client write IV:
  *** HEX DUMP
Server write IV:
  *** HEX DUMP
main, WRITE: TLSv1 Change Cipher Spec, length = 1
*** Finished
verify_data:  { XXX, ··· XXX }
***
main, WRITE: TLSv1 Handshake, length = **
main, READ: TLSv1 Change Cipher Spec, length = **
main, READ: TLSv1 Handshake, length = **
*** Finished
verify_data:  { XXX, ··· XXX }
***
%% Cached client session: [Session-3, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA]
main, WRITE: TLSv1 Application Data, length = **
main, READ: TLSv1 Application Data, length = **
main, WRITE: TLSv1 Application Data, length = **
main, WRITE: TLSv1 Application Data, length = **
main, READ: TLSv1 Application Data, length = **
main, WRITE: TLSv1 Application Data, length = **
main, WRITE: TLSv1 Application Data, length = **
main, READ: TLSv1 Application Data, length = **
main, WRITE: TLSv1 Application Data, length = **
main, WRITE: TLSv1 Application Data, length = **
main, READ: TLSv1 Application Data, length = **
main, WRITE: TLSv1 Application Data, length = **
main, WRITE: TLSv1 Application Data, length = **
main, READ: TLSv1 Application Data, length = **
main, WRITE: TLSv1 Application Data, length = **
main, WRITE: TLSv1 Application Data, length = **
main, READ: TLSv1 Application Data, length = **
main, WRITE: TLSv1 Application Data, length = **
main, WRITE: TLSv1 Application Data, length = **
main, READ: TLSv1 Application Data, length = **
main, WRITE: TLSv1 Application Data, length = **
main, WRITE: TLSv1 Application Data, length = **
main, READ: TLSv1 Application Data, length = **
main, WRITE: TLSv1 Application Data, length = **
main, WRITE: TLSv1 Application Data, length = ****
main, READ: TLSv1 Application Data, length = ***
main, WRITE: TLSv1 Application Data, length = **
main, WRITE: TLSv1 Application Data, length = **
main, READ: TLSv1 Application Data, length = **
main, called close()
main, called closeInternal(true)
main, SEND TLSv1 ALERT:  warning, description = close_notify
main, WRITE: TLSv1 Alert, length = **
main, called closeSocket(selfInitiated)
Message sent!
```

The previous logs shows two failed attempts at connecting, and a successful third one.

**EDIT 20160315:** As has been mentioned by commenters below, it seems like the **exchange.*.com** host is redirecting to different hosts, each with its own certificate, as the connection fails when presented with a certificate with **CN=smtpserver-ch-02**, while it is successful when presented with a certificate with **CN=smtpserver-ch-01**.

If that's the case, then maybe the solution is to do several runs of the *openssl* command in order to retrieve both certificates and add them to the truststore.

**EDIT (SOLVED):** The aforementioned solution worked, I launched the *openssl* command several times, and compared the resulting data until I isolated the two unique certificates I needed.

After importing them to the truststore, everything is working correctly.

Comment: Is the server part of any sort of cluster, load-balanced, or multi-tenant system where the host your client specifies might resolve to a different service?

Comment: @erickson I'm not sure, as the server configuraction, both for the Linux machine running the Tomcat server, as for the exchange smtp server, are handled by the client, I just manage the deployed Java app.

Only thing I'm kind of certain is that attempting to use a browser to retrieve the exchange.***.com site's certificate would not work, and I had to retrieve it via openssl with the -starttls option, so I guess there's an "internal" certificate of sorts, with the exchange address being a frontend (I'm not to knowledgable about server configuration though)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're getting two different certificates from two different servers so you'll have to add both of them to your trust store.  Or you can set the [mail.smtp.ssl.trust property](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/com/sun/mail/smtp/package-summary.html#mail.smtp.ssl.trust).

Comment: I really wanted to avoid resorting to making validation exceptions, but seems like it will be the way to go.